# Best way to affix EPS insulation panels to interior plaster walls?

Tags: insulation

My house was built in 1957 and there is little or no insulation in the exterior walls. To increase the R-value, I plan to put up 1-inch panels of expanded polystyrene, then use adhesive to attach 3D tiles made of plant fiber. For the insulating panels, should I use construction caulk, a special adhesive, double-sided gorilla tape, drywall screws, or something beyond my scant knowledge? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Better check with the codes in your area.
Also check with your insurance company as EPS board is not recommended or approved for interior use due to flame spread and smoke.
If it is approved you can use a dispersion adhesive for attachment to the plaster walls.
Also you may cause a moisture problem between the plaster and the backside of the EPS.

Comment: Thank you, Clarence. I hadn't considered the code issue. Also, I will get the panels with no foil barrier, or peel it off myself. I had read about moisture issues, so hope that would work. Was going to use drywall, but it is too heavy for me to lift in the 1" size.

Comment: I think it depends on the area and specific installations, but have seen it used for sound dampening in comercial installs inside locations.

Comment: In some cases it can be used in a wall cavity but must be protected by a fire rated material also the EPS must contain a fire retardant a lot of EPS manufactures do not add the fire retarder.